# ADODB.Stream error '800a0bbc' Write to file failed

Tags: asp-classic, adodb

I've weird and strange error showing while I change hosting provider which is:

> ADODB.Stream error '800a0bbc'
>
> Write to file failed.
>
> /cp/portal_upload.asp, line 63

I gave the needed permissions and it solve the update Access DB problem but file uploading still not fixed.

this is the code, thanks in advance:

```vbs
Public Sub Save(path)
    Dim streamFile, fileItem

    if Right(path, 1) <> "\" then path = path & "\"

    if not uploadedYet then Upload

    For Each fileItem In UploadedFiles.Items
        Set streamFile = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        streamFile.Type = 1
        streamFile.Open
        StreamRequest.Position=fileItem.Start
        StreamRequest.CopyTo streamFile, fileItem.Length
        streamFile.SaveToFile path & fileItem.FileName, 2  'This is line 63
        streamFile.close
        Set streamFile = Nothing
        fileItem.Path = path & fileItem.FileName
     Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe the path is invalid. Do a `Response.Write("path is: " & path & fileItem.FileName & "<br />")` and post what you get as result.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly check if `path & fileItem` is a valid address?
If the folders is not created, create it.
Also, recheck your permissions. Have you given `IUSR` the permission of "Full Control"?

Comment: `Have you given IUSER the permission of "Full Control"` how ?

Comment: Another possibility is that your server is out of disk space, as this happened to me.