# VBScript error ADODB.Stream : Write to the file failed

Tags: iis, vbscript, asp-classic, adodb

I am trying to run one script which parse url and projectname from file and try to download files from url into the zip format. I am seeing error this while writing file to the folder. I am using windows sserver 2012 R2

ADODB.Stream : Write to the file failed

I've verified IUSER and other users have full access to the target and source folder.

Here is the script. May I know if something I am missing here?

```
Dim URLFile 
Dim URLLine, URL, ProjectName
Dim xHttp, bStrm

Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
set fso = createobject("scripting.filesystemobject")
Set URLFile = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\Temp\Scripts\VBScripts\URLList.txt")


do while  not URLFile.AtEndOfStream

URLLine = URLFile.ReadLine()
'Wscript.Echo URLLine

if len(URLLine)>10 then
URL = Left(URLLine,inStr(URLLine,";")-1)
ProjectName = Right(URLLine,Len(URLLine)-inStr(URLLine,";"))
Set xHttp = createobject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
Set bStrm = createobject("Adodb.Stream")


xHttp.Open "GET", URL, False
xHttp.Send


with bStrm
   .type = 1 '//binary
   .open
   .write xHttp.responseBody
   .savetofile "C:\Backups\"&"Backup Zip All Files for "&ProjectName&"-"&cStr(Date)&".zip", 2 '//overwrite
  end with

Set xHttp = Nothing
Set bStrm = Nothing

end if

loop
```

[image]

Comment: Why did you tag this `PowerShell` ?

Comment: Whether you believe it or not it is a permissions issue, you need to check that you use `IUSR` as your `ApplicationPoolIdentity` as well as the anonymous user account. If not you'll need to give the `IIS_IUSRS` system group write access to the folder.

Comment: Does it work properly locally? This error only appears on iis? If so, then it should be a permission issue, please recheck your permissions. Have you given IUSER the permission of "Full Control"?

Comment: Yes This works properly locally . In server , I have Full Control to multiple users including IUSER and myself. Attached screenshot of permissions

Comment: @ronypatil like I already said check the `AppPoolIdentity` in your IIS Application Pool settings to see if it is set to `IUSR`, if not you will need to check what it is set to. By default it’s set to `ApplicationPoolIdentity` which means it uses the `IIS_IUSRS` security group for it’s permission level.

Comment: @samwu btw it’s `IUSR` not `IUSER` and it wouldn’t need "Full Control" that is over kill, "Write" would be enough.

Comment: @ronypatil you may find [Recommendations for Setting up Websites in IIS](https://gist.github.com/lankymart/4b8c9f650ee524d7ab4c3fca76b75611) helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ADODB.Stream error '800a0bbc' Write to file failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16652896/adodb-stream-error-800a0bbc-write-to-file-failed)

Comment: To confirm that it is indeed a permissions error, and not path or ZIP module fault, try setting write and execute permissions for EVERYONE on the work folder, if only temporarily while you test.

Answer (score -1):

If you get past the permissions thing by making read/write for Everyone, all you need then is a module to perform the ZIP function.

I usually use a commercial DLL and there are many to choose from.

Comment: I fail to see how this answers the question.

Comment: It works for me when zipping on the fly for download.