# Error when i upload file except txt ADODB.Stream error '800a0bbc'

Tags: asp-classic

error showing whenever I try to upload file except for txt, this error showing when I try upload jpeg file, there is no exception any specific file that can upload in the code, it should upload a jpeg file or pdf, but it showing error like this:

```
ADODB.Stream error '800a0bbc' 

Write to file failed. 

/ros/ROS/freeaspupload.asp, line 241
```

this is the freeaspupload code where the error came

```
    Public Sub SaveParkir(path, prefixFile)
        Dim streamFile, fileItem, i

        if Right(path, 1) <> "\" then path = path & "\"

        if not uploadedYet then Upload

        i = 1
        For Each fileItem In UploadedFiles.Items
            
            Set streamFile = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
            streamFile.Type = 1
            streamFile.Open
            StreamRequest.Position=fileItem.Start
            StreamRequest.CopyTo streamFile, fileItem.Length
            streamFile.SaveToFile path & prefixFile & fileItem.FileName, 2
            streamFile.close
            Set streamFile = Nothing
            fileItem.Path = path & prefixFile & fileItem.FileName
            i = i + 1
            
             'response.Write fileItem.Path
         Next
         'response.Write i
        
    End Sub
```

what is the problem? how can i fix this? thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ADODB.Stream error '800a0bbc' Write to file failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16652896/adodb-stream-error-800a0bbc-write-to-file-failed)

Comment: The problem is `ADODB.Stream` cannot write the uploaded file to the file path you have specified.  Check the path is correct and the `ApplicationPoolIdentity` has at least `write` permission to the file path.